# XCODE Console message Numbers between brackets correspondent with line code?

Tags: ios, xcode

while running my iOS app i get the message:

> 2017-11-04 15:33:02.873595+0100 DagBoek[71486:4321269] ***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

in the XCODE console

`DagBoek[71486:4321269]` What do the numbers between the brackets mean ?
Can they help me to find where in my code the problem is ?

Thanks

Comment: To find the line where the error occurred, set an [Objective-C exception break point](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION28).

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't really help much. The first number, 71486 in your example, is the process ID (PID). The second number (4321269) is a thread ID of sorts, but Apple's diagnostic and debugging tools seem to use different thread ID schemes in different contexts, so it's mostly useless.